# Is it possible to get an ROC curve using Relu activation?

Tags: image-classification, activation-function, roc

Based on my understanding, given that Relu doesn't provide probabilities unlike Softmax, it's not possible to plot an ROC curve. However, is there some way to convert the output from a Relu to something like an ROC curve. I'm interested in doing so because it's important for my project (image classification) to be able to adjust the classification thresholds.

Comment: Are you sure you mean to use relu in the output layer? You do not need a bounded output to be able to do a ROC curve (though you might use a different approach to the code if you don’t have probability outputs), though relu would not be the standard choice for the output layer activation function.

Comment: You can use sigmoid activation, and then apply the required threshold.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD’Sa Apply sigmoid when, instead of or after the relu? I still think the OP doesn’t mean to use relu in the output layer, though.

Comment: @Dave, I meant instead of reLu. The OP mentions "convert the outputs from a ReLU", by this I assume, that OP wants to use ReLU instead of softmax.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD’Sa Okay, so we’re in agreement that this is unorthodox and might be a mistake. // Mistake or not, I hope to get some time to be able to post an answer in the coming days. You don’t need probability outputs to do ROC (though particular software implementations may have that expectation).

Comment: Eitherways, I feel OP should provide a little more details on the question. Especially on what is the desired task and if there is a specific intention to use ReLu.

Comment: Some of the models/ train code found online uses a Relu or Linear as the final classification layer. I think the term activation layer I've used is a mistake, sorry for the confusion. I was wondering if it was possible to plot an ROC curve if the final tensor I get isn't a bounded probability or isn't the result of a Softmax.

Comment: As my answer shows, you don’t need a probability to do a RUC curve. However, I’d like to see where they are using relu in the final layer. Linear make sense (neural net can be used for regression problems), but relu surprises me.

Comment: @Dave. Like this example in [Pytorch](https://colab.research.google.com/github/sanchit2843/MLBasics/blob/master/IntelClassificationKaggle/Pytorch%20transfer%20learning%20tutorial%20%5B93%25acc%5D.ipynb#scrollTo=0tror3rLbi37). But I now I realize that this stems from my misunderstanding about nn.CrossEntropyLoss. Most of the code don't have the softmax layer in model. This is because nn.CrossEntropyLoss accounts for it. Hence, why the last layer is linear. Regarding relu, I think I might have gotten confused between relu as a activation function in between layers vs the final layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**YES**

The typical way to do a ROC curve is to have probability outputs, set a threshold, and calculate the sensitivity and specificity.

```
y | prob
----------
0 | 0.2
0 | 0.3
1 | 0.7
1 | 0.8
```

At a threshold of 0, we classify everyting as $1$, so sensitivity of $1$ and specificity of $0$. At a threshold of $0.25$, we get $0,1,1,1$, so sensitivity of $1$ and specificity of $0.5$. Et cetera...

Plot those $(1, 1)$, $(0.5, 1)$ points to start building your ROC curve.

This idea of setting a threshold and calculating the sensitivity and specificity does not assume probability outputs, so let's do the same with non-probability outputs.

```
y | output
----------
0 | 2
0 | 3
1 | 7
1 | 8
```

At a threshold of 0, we classify everyting as $1$, so sensitivity of $1$ and specificity of $0$. At a threshold of $2.5$, we get $0,1,1,1$, so sensitivity of $1$ and specificity of $0.5$. Et cetera...